# NullPointerException in ejb injection

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ejb

Why I have `NullPointerException`? I have done everything right! I have 2 easy classes and it can't be wrong! Sorry for stupid names but I commented almost all code and it still not working!

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pl.take.server.model.WholesaleREST.getCars(WholesaleREST.java:34) [:]
```

Rest class:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/wholesale")
public class WholesaleREST{

    @EJB
    private WholesaleEJB2 wholesaleEJB2;

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    public String getCars() {
        String string = wholesaleEJB2.createClient2(); //LINE 34
        return string;
    }
```

EJB class:

```
@Stateless
public class WholesaleEJB2 {

    public String createClient2() {
        return("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try put `@LocalBean` on `WholesaleEJB2 `

Comment: Didn't help, still NullPointer

Comment: Is the only @EJB that returns null? Are you injecting another in other class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with EJB, but it looks like your data member named wholesaleEJB2 is null.  Perhaps if you change the line that declares that member to read

```
private WholesaleEJB2 wholesaleEJB2 = new WholesaleEJB2();
```

you would not have a NullPointerException.  I'm assuming here that WholesaleEJB2 has a no-argument constructor, since you do not show any constructor in that class.

Comment: I have no idea why, but this worked. This look like an easy mistake but look this tutorials: 
http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_ejb_3_13

http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/rest-on-ejb/README.html
There is alway construction:
@EJB Class field;

Comment: In the unit test at adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_ejb_3_13 they do explicitly construct (or construct mocks of) the objects that are annotated with `@EJB`. I didn't see use of `@EJB` at the other link you provided.

Comment: what is the rationale for instatiating the bean?  incidentally, you don't need to declare it, as it was already "declared" with the @EJB injection...